# Indentation error

Tags: python

Cuando intento cargar este código me salta que en la linea 3 hay un error de indentación alguien sabe como resolverlo?

```
 accion = input()
def h():
while accion != "D":   
    print("error")
    accion=input()
    if accion == "D":        
        print("2")
```

Comment: Hola D4hen, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. El único error que hay en tu código **tal como está en la pregunta** es que `accion==input()` debe ser `accion = input()` (asignación).  Al último `print` le sobra un espacio de identación pero esto no causa ningún error. ¿Es este todo tu código o tienes más en el módulo? ¿Cual es la linea 3? Según lo que muestras sería `print("error")` pero como comento no hay ningún error de identación en ese código. si tienes más código agregalo, ahora mismo no es posible reproducir tu problema. Un Saludo.

Comment: Perdon me he quivocadp escribiendolo es este

Comment: `accion = input() `
 `def h(): `
 `while accion != "D": `   
     `print("error") `
     `accion=input() `
     `if accion == "D": `        
          `print("2")`
Es todo el codigo que tengo, cada frase es una linea, como hago que salga en vertical?

Comment: D4hen usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/271444/edit) que hay debajo de la pregunta y añade el código en ella dónde lo puedes formatear adecaudamente, los comentarios son muy mal sitio para compartir código porque no permiten formatear bloques de código como has observado, más cuando el problema es de identación... XD

Comment: Recuerda que Python usa la identación para delimitar los bloques de código, para que el while esté dentro de la función debes identarlo. Además de esto, accion es una variable global, debes especificar que lo es para poder reasignar en la fucnión. Mirate el ejemplo online https://repl.it/repls/RepentantBeautifulHarddrive

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente el problema es  que te falta una identación tras la declaración de la función, recuerda añadir las demás identaciones necesarias por haber añadido la ya mencionada. En el siguiente código he eliminado la declaración de la función ya que la considero innecesaria si lo único que quieres es que el código nos diga si la letra que inserto es la "D".

```
accion=input("introduce letra")

while accion!="D":
    print("error")
    accion=input("introduce letra")
    if accion == "D":
        print("2")
```